# Retrieve year, month, day, hour, second and timezone from a String and convert to DateTime

Tags: java, regex, date, jodatime

I want to get a DateTime object using a String with this format, yyyyMMddHHmmss+timezone,

As an example:

20131216014500+0000

It looks like I can use the DateTimeFormatter but I don't really know how, then I am using regular expression to create the DateTime objects. For that I am using this:

```
Pattern.compile("([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])\\+([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(timestamp);
String match = m.group();
int year = Integer.parseInt(m.group(0));
int monthOfYear = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
int hourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
int minuteOfHour = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
int secondOfMinute = Integer.parseInt(m.group(5));
// TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("");
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute);
```

Here I have two problems, one is that I don't know how to set the TimeZone.

The second one is that running this I get java.lang.IllegalStateException.

Any help?

Comment: Please use the `DateTimeFormatter`. There are tons of examples online and the javadoc is even better.

Comment: ^ agreed. Also, with regex, you don't need to repeat the integer pattern like that.`([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})`, etc, works just fine. If you're ever in doubt, http://regexpal.com/ is a great little site!

Comment: This quote fits quite nicely here: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' -[Jamie Zawinski](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Unlike java.util.Date, a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) knows its own time zone. You can specify the time zone in the formatter definition if you wish (call `withZone`). Or you can create a new DateTime instance set to a zone, as seen below, by calling `toDateTime` and passing a `DateTimeZone` instance.

```java
String string = "20131216014500+0000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( string ); // Default time zone.

// Shift time zone to UTC/GMT.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Shift time zone to a named time zone.
// Guessing that "Europe/Madrid" is appropriate for Málaga Spain.
DateTime dateTimeMálaga = dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Madrid" ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMálaga: " + dateTimeMálaga );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-12-15T17:45:00.000-08:00
dateTimeUtc: 2013-12-16T01:45:00.000Z
dateTimeMálaga: 2013-12-16T02:45:00.000+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the way to go here. There are java libraries that already solved this problem. See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
y   Year
M   Month
d   day
H   hour
m   minute
s   second
Z   timezone (RFC 822)
```

This should probably do it:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ");
Date result =  df.parse(yourString);  
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(result); //to get a joda DateTime object
```

---

Edit: JodaTime has a similar class.

> The pattern syntax is mostly compatible with java.text.SimpleDateFormat

```
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ");
 DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(yourString);
```

See [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: OP is using jodatime.

Comment: yes he does. you can easily pass a `java.util.Date` object to the `DateTime` constructor and get a joda `DateTime` object. and there is a similar thing in jodatime too, I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thnaks, that's what I wanted you to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: ...